# Getting Ajax data into a table, and building a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

At the moment, I am reading data from an ajax call and appending it to a table on my page. This works fine, however I would like to also take one of the pieces of data and turn it into a hyperlink.

This is my current code:

```
$.each(opts, function(i, d) {
$('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').text(d.PropNo),
    $('<td>').text(d.StoreName),
    $('<td>').text(d.StoreAddress),
    $('<td>').text(d.ClientName),
    $('<td>').text(d.StoreTypeName)
).appendTo('#StoresTable');
```

I've tried building the hyperlink by adding HTML elements to the append statement like this:

```
$('<td>').text("<a href=viewstore.php?StoreID="+d.StoreID+">click here to view the store</a>")
```

But this just results in the HTML elements being treated as text rather than elements.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: use `$('<td>').html(...)`

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea that I could even do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I show you another way:

```js
$('input').click(function(){
  $('table').append('\
    <tr>\
      <td><a href="#">dfs</a></td>\
    </tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th>title</th></tr>
</table>
<input type=button value=add>
```